# Passar variavel PHP em JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Quero passar uma variavel que esta em php, para JavaScript. Por exemplo isto:

```
<?php
    $color = "Red";
?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var color = <?php $color ?>;

                alert("color: " + color);
            </script>
```

Experimentei este codigo, mas nao funciona.

Comment: Acha que esta resposta foi correta para a sua pergunta? Caso sim pode marcar como certa.

Answer (score 3):

Vejo três problemas:

#### #1 você quer uma *string*

Então vai ter de ter aspas:

```
var color = "codigo_da_côr";
            ^             ^
```

#### #2 falta um ponto e virgula: `;`

Falta um `;` a seguir à variavel PHP, deve ser:

```
<?php $color; ?>
            ^
```

#### #3 falta um echo

Como o Jader notou bem, falta fazer o echo da variável...

Pode fazer `<?=$color;?>` se não quiser usar `echo` (atalho), ou tem de ter `echo` assim `<?php echo $color; ?>`

#### Código correto:

```
var color = "<?php echo $color; ?>";
```

Comment: Ainda esta faltando um echo

Comment: @Jader verdade! juntei, obrigado